# "Nonlinear" random spatial field: an example

Tags: autocorrelation, mutual-information, nonlinear, random-field

I want to generate a "nonlinear" random spatial field in the sense that the autocorrelation function in function of the lag/distance $h$, $\rho(h)$, should be not equal to the $R(h)$ coefficient that is $R(h) = \sqrt{1-exp(-2I(h))}$, where $I(h)$ is the mutual information in function of the lag/distance h.
Any suggestions?